# How to print an array element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code to get weather details of cities.
When I load the page, It is providing correct weather details of given cities by URL get method. But can't print the city name of each result. In my example, It always says "Sydney"

How can I print each city name with the result?

Code:

```js
x = window.location.search.substr(6);
y = x.split("%2C");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b1').click(function() {

    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

      city = y[i];

      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city +
          "&units=metric" +
          "&appid=ace585585ed8eb42338b8e663fe0170e",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          var w = showd(data);
          var para2 = $("<p></p>").text(city);
          var para = $("<p></p>").text(w);
          $("body").append(para2, para);
        }
      });

      function showd(data) {
        return data.weather[0].description;

      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("b1").click();
});
```

```html
<Script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></Script>

<button style="visibility:hidden;" id="b1">Click</button><br><br>
<p id="data"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
```

URL:

```
file:///C:/wamp/www/aTravelz/checkweather.html?wthr=Moscow%2CLondon%2CColombo%2CSydney
```

Result:

```
Sydney

overcast clouds

Sydney

light intensity shower rain

Sydney

few clouds

Sydney

broken clouds
```

Comment: Spend some time reading [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using **last value of city (after the for-loop has been completed) will be used** since *AJAX response* will come after the same.

You need to **lock the value of `city`** for each *AJAX request*

```
 (function(city){ $.ajax({
           //rest of the ajax code stays as is
 }))(city);
```

Or you can use `let` instead of `var` as **@xander said in the comments** (as shown in demo as well)

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [ 1,2,3 ];
for( var counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++ )
{
   let c = arr[ counter ];
   setTimeout( function(){
      console.log(c)
   }, 100);
}
```

Comment: It should also work if the city variable is scoped to the for-block, e.g. with `let city = y[i]` when using ES6.

Comment: @xander AJAX call will still be inside the for-loop so it will still have the access to the `city`.

Comment: yes but the success closure will capture a different `city` variable with every ajax-request when defined with `let` instead of `var`, so it should work if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @xander `city` will still be block scoped and AJAX call will fall under the same block, isn't it?

Comment: @xander is correct about `let` in `for` loop. Op's use of globals is not good either way

Comment: @xander You are right, I tested as well.

Comment: @gurvinder372 yeah it's a little mind bending at first, but for me the `var` keyword is worse because it scopes the variable to the function, not the block you define it in (like `let` does).